# Issue getting simple Fetch working in Netlify Functions

Tags: node.js, cdn, netlify

I've been working through the workshops for Netlify functions and have stumbled getting a simple Fetch response to work. When running the sample at:
https://github.com/DavidWells/netlify-functions-workshop/blob/master/lessons-code-complete/use-cases/5-fetching-data/functions/node-fetch/node-fetch.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts'

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {   let response   
  try {
    response = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT)
    // handle response   
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: err.message
      })
  }   }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: response
    })   } }
```

but I just get the following response:

> {"data":{"size":0,"timeout":0}}

The build process is working fine, and I've tried other end points but all give the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working version of your original code using **`node-fetch`** and the callback.

```
// import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const checkStatus = (res) => {
  if (res.ok) { // res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300
      return res.json()
  } else {
      throw new Error(res.statusText);
  }
}

exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts')
    const data = await checkStatus(response)
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    callback(error)
  }
}
```

***Note:*** Netlify functions are just AWS functions and you can read about the [AWS Lambda Function Handler in the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)

> For async functions, you return a response, error, or promise to the runtime instead of using callback.

I like to use the method recommended in the docs, since it is supported and save the callback for non-async functions.

Here is a working version returning a promise to the async function instead.

```
// import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts')
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) { // res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300
        return res.json();
      } else {
        resolve({ statusCode: res.status || 500, body: res.statusText })
      };
    })
    .then(data =>{
      const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
      resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      resolve({ statusCode: err.statusCode || 500, body: err.message })
    })
  })
}
```

This is just an example and there are other ways to handle the errors, but this example resolved the response rather than rejecting. It is not tested as a production example, but gives you an idea of the difference.

[Here are some examples of Netlify functions.](https://functions.netlify.com/examples)

Comment: Thanks it worked but I did have to change the top line to:
const fetch = require('node-fetch') for it to work with Netlify Functions, not sure if that's a build issue or not

Comment: Oh, right, these are pre-compiled into the functions folder from a source location using webpack during the build. If you just use these as your nodejs functions, they need the change you mentioned. I bundle up my dependencies during my build using the `netlify-lambda` cli, so I don't have to bring along a `node_modules` folder with them for external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

On the `handle response` line you’ll want to await the json result:

```
response = await response.json();
```

Check the [MDN article for Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I switched to the Axios library and it worked first time:

```
const axios = require('axios')

const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  let response
  try {
    response = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT)
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: err.message
      })
    }
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      data: response.data
    })
  }
}
```